# Sum, Average, Lowest and Highest scores of user input (Conditional Control Structures)

Tags: java, sum, average

I have the following homework assignment. Our teacher hasn't taught us well, so I need extra help.

Write a Java program that will input five scores of a student in five quizzes.  Output the sum and average of five scores.  Determine and display the highest and lowest score.

This is how I am stuck now. I only have up to Q3 last time and it only shows the average and the lowest score with no highest score. Kindly help me make this work!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class Quizzes
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5;
    double average;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Quizzes: ");
    Q1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    Q2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    Q3 = keyboard.nextInt();
    Q4 = keyboard.nextInt();
    Q5 = keyboard.nextInt();

    average = (Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4 + Q5) / 5;
    System.out.println("Average Score is: " + average);

    if (Q1 < Q2 && Q1 < Q3) {
        System.out.println("The lowest score is: " + Q1);
    } else if (Q2 < Q1 && Q2 < Q3) {
        System.out.println("The lowest score is: " + Q2);
    } else if (Q3 < Q1 && Q2 < Q3) {
        System.out.println("The lowest score is: " + Q3);
    } else if (Q1 > Q2 && Q1 > Q3) {
        System.out.println("The highest score is: " + Q1);
    } else if (Q2 > Q1 && Q2 > Q3) {
        System.out.println("The highest score is: " + Q2);        
    } else if (Q3 > Q3 && Q1 > Q2) {
        System.out.println("The highest score is: " + Q3);
    } else {
        System.out.println("The lowest score is: " + Q3);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It's pretty obvious from the copy/paste nature of your question that it's an assignment question. We don't mind helping with those but the way it's formatted at the moment is a "do it for me" which we're not here to do. If we were, we'd get the degree at the end ;). Update you question with some examples of what you've tried and we'll help if we can.

Comment: Sorry if it appears like that but actually it is because I know that with the number of my assignments (20) and deadline (day after tomorrow) and with the knowledge taught by our teacher "less than 15%", I am sure that I cannot finish all of these on time. I am a very good student when it comes to studying my lessons, just that like what I've said, our teacher didn't teach us well, that is why I am here to seek help from you guys.. I am not meant to just let you do it and I will just pass it to our teacher. I have a very little time to learn it all but rest assured that what I'm gonna get here

Comment: I'd raise that with your institution rather than here. If he's as bad as you're saying, you won't have been the only one to experience this.

Comment: I will surely review them, practice and learn. That is my purpose. I'm not just gonna let you do it for my grades, I just don't have time since deadline is merely 24 hours. I have been doing these for days.

Comment: You won't learn anything if we just dump a solution here.

Comment: ok... looks like you don't understand my situation but thanks anyhow!

Comment: You misunderstand, I absolutely do understand your situation. Actually I've been in the same situation. I resolved it by notifying the institution ***before*** assignments were due imminently. The way it looks to me is you've left it to the last minute, panicked, and started to blame it on your professor. If this really was the case that you were badly educated, you should have raised that **before** the night before your assignment was due.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your current solution you have a couple of basic issues such as `else if (Q3 > Q3)`.

You also don't check for equality i.e. `if (Q2 >= Q3)`.

The major issue with your current technique is that you have a load of if/else statements, a better solution would be to use an Array like below:

```
public class Quizzes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5;
        double average = 0;
        double max = 0;
        double count = 0;
        double[] userInput = new double[5];

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Quizzes: ");
        System.out.println("");
        Q1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        userInput[0] = Q1;
        Q2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        userInput[1] = Q2;
        Q3 = keyboard.nextInt();
        userInput[2] = Q3;
        Q4 = keyboard.nextInt();
        userInput[3] = Q4;
        Q5 = keyboard.nextInt();
        userInput[4] = Q5;
        keyboard.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
            count = count + userInput[i];
            average = count / 5;
        }
        System.out.println("Average Score is: " + average);
        Arrays.sort(userInput);
        System.out.println("The lowest score is: " + userInput[0]);
        max = userInput[userInput.length - 1];
        System.out.println("The highest score is: " + max);
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

Now that you have informed us you cannot use an Array then below code will do the job without modifying your original method too much:

```
public class Quizzes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5;
        double average = 0;
        double lowest = 0;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Quizzes: ");
        System.out.println("");
        Q1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
        Q2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
        Q3 = keyboard.nextDouble();
        Q4 = keyboard.nextDouble();
        Q5 = keyboard.nextDouble();
        keyboard.close();

        average = (Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4 + Q5) / 5;
        System.out.println("Average Score is: " + average);

        if (Q1 <= Q2 && Q1 <= Q3 && Q1 <= Q4 && Q1 <= Q5) {
            lowest = Q1;
        } else if (Q2 <= Q1 && Q2 <= Q3 && Q2 <= Q4 && Q2 <= Q5) {
            lowest = Q2;
        } else if (Q3 <= Q1 && Q3 <= Q2 && Q3 <= Q4 && Q3 <= Q5) {
            lowest = Q3;
        } else if (Q4 <= Q1 && Q4 <= Q2 && Q4 <= Q3 && Q4 <= Q5) {
            lowest = Q4;
        } else if (Q5 <= Q1 && Q5 <= Q2 && Q5 <= Q3 && Q5 <= Q4) {
            lowest = Q5;
        }

        System.out.println("The lowest score is: " + lowest);
        // THEN DO SIMILAR TO GET HIGHEST SCORE
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry but I have not included that we should do it in Conditional Control Structures not with array. I will save this anyway and it will serve as my references. I will practice with the help of this so thank you!

Comment: @Lance kindly help me here too...please.. Smoggers done it using array, my mistake though because I have not included that it should be done with Conditional Control Structures.

Comment: haven't you seen it yet? here's the URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464628/sum-average-lowest-and-highest-scores-of-user-input-conditional-control-struc?noredirect=1#comment52791917_32464628

Comment: @FinnDonovan I've edited my answer, please upvote so that my time and effort towards producing 2 suitable solutions is rewarded :)

Comment: Sure @smoggers... upvoted yours already though I am confused in editing with the help from Mike which I inserted, I was able to come up with correct average, highest score, lowest score but not the sum as it is always zero. I tried the last one you provided but it only returned the average and lowest score. My eyes are burning now and it is already 5:40am and I have to review for a short exam today so I must continue this after I get home around 11pm... see you and thank you so much for your help.. If only I can upvote every reply here... thanks from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: Thank you @Smoggers... it's now working... the SUM is not included but I have managed to insert it and also the highest.. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can also insert these values into an array, go over this array and look for the min and max values.

Like this:

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
arr[0] = Q1;
arr[1] = Q2;
arr[2] = Q3;
arr[3] = Q4;
arr[4] = Q5;


int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){

    min = Math.min(min, arr[i]);
    max = Math.min(max, arr[i]);

}
```

Comment: hi again...Am I allowed to post an "answer" to my own question just to be able to post what I have done in my program which I want the readers/solvers to see? I cannot post the codes as comment.

Comment: yes you can, you can make it as an answer or either as an edit in your question.

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor: no, we discourage answers in questions here, unless the question is closed and a new answer is not possible. Adding a self-answer is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not allowed to use arrays and/or loops, here's one way to do it. You can see why arrays make it more concise; you would not want to do this for 100 questions. I have left out computation of the maximum, since it's trivially similar.

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
if (Q1 < min) {
    min = Q1;
}
if (Q2 < min) {
    min = Q2;
}
if (Q3 < min) {
    min = Q3;
}
if (Q4 < min) {
    min = Q4;
}
if (Q5 < min) {
    min = Q5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mike... I will try it now with what you provided.. I can only differentiate them after fully understanding all my lessons since my teacher haven't really taught us well... we only have a meeting once per week and kills me taking all this..will get back to you after few minutes..

Comment: I copied what Smoggers had provided and replaced the arrays with what you provided and it worked, the problem is the average is always zero and the sum don't appear.

Comment: this is what I did.                                                                                                                                                     double Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5;
        double average = 0;
        double max = 0;
        double count = 0;
        double[] userInput = new double[5];
        double sum = count;
        average = count/5;